# Writing to wofstream generates exception

Tags: c++

I try just to write some wchar_t* to a file but the command line output of the compiled program is as bellow. Essentially the program hangs when trying to write the greek string.

```
el_GR.UTF-8
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
Ακυρώθηκε (core dumped)
```

Source code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <wchar.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    printf("%s\n",setlocale(LC_ALL,""));
    wofstream f("xxx.txt", ios::out);
    if(f.is_open())
    {
        try
        {
            f.write(L"good",4);
            f.flush();
            f.write(L"καλημερα",8);
            f.close();
        }
        catch (int e)
        {
            cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e <<endl;
        }

        printf("hello world\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Why ?

Comment: It's a bug, as nothing in the iostreams should ever throw an int. What's the compiler and overall system? Are there warnings? What is the encoding of the source code? And finally, what is the value of `e`?

Comment: the value of e is 20. I use g++ and compile with no warnings. It seems as a kind of initialization should be done.

Answer (score 1):

The stream doesn't takes the locale from the environment.
I addeed:

```
#include <locale>
locale loc("el_GR.utf8");
f.imbue(loc);
```

So the stream now holds the locale to use ( If I am wrong please correct ).

The code that works correctly is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    locale loc("el_GR.utf8");
    wcout<<"Hi I am starting Ξεκινάμε"<<endl;
    cout<<"%s\n"<<setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.utf8")<<endl;
    wofstream f("xxx.txt", ios::out);
        if(f.is_open()){
            f.imbue(loc);

            f.write(L"good",4);f.flush();
            f.write(L"καλημέρα",8);
            f.close();
            cout<<"fileClosed"<<endl;
  }

    cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: You can use `getenv` to fetch the locale from the environment.

Comment: Or just use `locale loc(setlocale(LC_ALL, ""))` to take all of the relevant envvars into account...